# Using typescript with react, stateless component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, state

I was wondering what the difference between these are, assuming I am not using state:

```
1. export class SkillList extends React.Component<SkillListProps> {}
2. export class SkillList extends React.Component<SkillListProps, any> {}
3. export class SkillList extends React.Component<SkillListProps, {}> {}
```

Or do they all behave in the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at [the type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react) and find out:

```
interface Component<P = {}, S = {}> extends ComponentLifecycle<P, S> { }
class Component<P, S> {
    /* ... */
}
```

Both `P` (the type parameter for the props) and `S` (the type parameter for the state) default to `{}`, meaning that both the props and state have the type of an empty object.

So in the cases you've specified:

1. You don't provide a type for `S`, so it defaults to `{}`.
2. You provide `any` as the type for `S` - this is *not* the same as `{}`, as it allows you to set the state to anything at all (a number, a string, etc.). I have no idea if that'll actually work in practice, given the way the `setState` API works, but you can try it if you want.
3. You provide `{}` as the type for `S`, which is the same as the default.

So in short, 1 and 3 are the same, but 2 is not.

Answer (score 0):

For stateless components there is a special type:

```
interface StatelessProps {}

const stateless: React.SFC<StatelessProps> = (props) => {
    return <div />
}
```